# How to select range of rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (from a weirdly-formatted Excel file) that has sections of data in the rows. An example like this:

| Name | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **First Group Header** | some data | some more data |
| First Group Data | some data | some more data |
| First Group Data | some data | some more data |
|  |  |  |
| **Second Group Header** | some data | some more data |
| Second Group Data | some data | some more data |
| Second Group Data | some data | some more data |
| Second Group Data | some data | some more data |
| Second Group Data | some data | some more data |
|  |  |  |
| **Third Group Header** | some data | some more data |
| Second Group Data | some data | some more data |

**Question**: How do I get individual dataframes for the Headers and associated data rows? The main issue is the range for each section of data is variable and can change over time, however the header names remain the same.

Comment: Are the overall headers (`Name`, `Data1`, `Data2`)  always located at a constant cell coordinate? Are the sections separated by a blank line?

Comment: @CodeDifferent Unfortunately, the headers are not in a constant cell coordinate due to the data for each section changing over time (sometimes more data in a section, sometimes less). The sections are not always separated by a blank line either. The only constant is the header names will always be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use the following to get the different headers grouped together. It should allow you to add more headers if you would like, but does take a small amount of Tech Debt to keep current (unless there is more to your table I can't see that you could work more with). This also assumes that you don't have that line between the different groups. If you do then I would simply remove those with a dropna() as needed.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

header_list = ['First Group Header', 'Second Group Header', 'Third Group Header']
df['GROUPER'] = np.where(df['Name'].isin(header_list), df['Name'], np.nan)
df['GROUPER'] = df['GROUPER'].ffill()
```

Comment: This option works well. However if I just wanted to select First and Second Headers, the .ffill() would apply Second Group Header to the rows for Third Group Header (and any rows beyond) since there is only NAN rows.

Comment: You should still be able to use the code, and if you wanted to select only the first and second header group you would then just have to write a `df_specific = df.loc[df['GROUPER'].isin('First Group Header', 'Second Group Header'])` I guess I don't understand your format enough to understand why you would bring back the header for 1 and 2, but not for 3, but include the data for 3

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. My data includes a lot of sections of headers and associated data. I realize my example wasn't the best representation. I guess I will have to ffill() every single header and then use your df.loc suggestion to pull the required data that I need.

Edit - It will just require a lot of upkeep if there are new sections added.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following solution

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["1st header","A","B","2nd header","AA","BB","CC","DD","3rd header","AAA"],"col1":[1,2,3,10,20,30,40,50,100,200],"col2":[2,4,6,20,40,60,80,100,200,400]})
df["groupn"] = df["Name"].str.contains("header").cumsum()
group_dfs = [d for n, d in df.groupby("groupn")]
# group_dfs is now list of pd.DataFrames
for g_df in group_dfs:
    print(g_df)
    print("=====")
```

gives output

```
         Name  col1  col2  groupn
0  1st header     1     2       1
1           A     2     4       1
2           B     3     6       1
=====
         Name  col1  col2  groupn
3  2nd header    10    20       2
4          AA    20    40       2
5          BB    30    60       2
6          CC    40    80       2
7          DD    50   100       2
=====
         Name  col1  col2  groupn
8  3rd header   100   200       3
9         AAA   200   400       3
=====
```

Explanation: you need to have function which will give `True`s for headers and `False`s for non-headers, I check if `Name` contains substring `header` but other check might be done if required, then I use cumulative sum which gives number of group, this is possible as `True` and `False` are assumed to be `1` and `0` respectively when needed in `python`, then I GROUP BY that column and create list of sub-dataframes. Observe that they have `groupn` column, which you might elect to drop if it is no longer required.

Comment: This is a great approach thank you. What if I had a list of header names (meaning "header" isn't always in the name of a header row)?

Comment: @Mark then you might use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) rather than `str.contains`, in my example it would be `df["Name"].isin(["1st header","2nd header","3rd header"]).cumsum()`